# FitToPagesTall method issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have faced an issue with For Each loop and FitToPages. File has 82 sheets.

Here is my code:

```
Sub printSet()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lasrow As Integer
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lasrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        sht.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("A1:D" & lasrow).Address
        sht.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
    Next
End Sub
```

The print area is selected perfectly... But each sheet is divided into 4 pages in the print preview window, which is not good at all.

Where is a mistake? Because the file is compiling without any errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! I missed .Zoom = False in PageSetup:

```
Sub printSet()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lasrow As Integer
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lasrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        sht.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("A1:D" & lasrow).Address
        With sht.PageSetup
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
    Next
```